# Chromium ignores user data relocation command line switch?

Tags: windows, portable, chromium

I'm trying to make Chromium portable, and according to [this page](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) I have to add `--user-data-dir=<dir>` as a command line-switch to chromium in order to use a custom directory to save personal data.

This is what I did:

1. Downloaded the latest Windows chromium build (http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/Win_Webkit_Latest/4294/chrome-win32.zip)
2. Extracted to a directory and within the directory I created a new one named `userdata`.
3. `cd`'d to the right directory and executed this command: `chrome.exe --user-data-dir=userdata`.

However, I noticed no files were made in `userdata` and after checking I see that the userdata is saved in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default` (the default) instead.

What did I do wrong?

---

Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the complete path to your data directory.

For instance, if you've extracted it to `C:\Chrome`, and created a folder called userdata inside that, you need to run

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:\Chrome\userdata"
```

Its always good to use quotes in windows arguments.

Also you can try running

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir=".\userdata\"
```

Here . refers to the current directory(`c:\Chrome\`) in this case

(It might work, but I don't have a Windows sytem right now to test it)

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but I'll accept it.